# Class not found in the classpath

Tags: java, classpath, classnotfoundexception, classnotfound

Good evening!

I have a problem. I want to fuzz a  from [this link](https://github.com/ispras/oss-sydr-fuzz/wiki/Fuzzing-json%E2%80%90sanitizer-%28Java%29-project-with-sydr%E2%80%90fuzz-%28Jazzer-backend%29-%28rus%29#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5).
I've created a project, it's his sctructure if it's important:

```
├── BUILD
├── build.sh
├── DenylistFuzzer.iml
├── pom.xml
├── project.yaml
├── src
│   └── Deny
│       └── DenylistFuzzer.java
└── target
    ├── archive-tmp
    ├── Deny
    │   └── DenylistFuzzer.class
    ├── DenylistFuzzer-1.0.jar
    ├── DenylistFuzzer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    └── maven-archiver
        └── pom.properties
```

I have json-sanitazer and jazzer-api dependencies for the build in the `pom.xml` file. After all, I've run `mvn package` command (just like it's recommended) and wanted to build fuzz-target. But I ran into the problem that even though I use the javac command as instructed and the .jar file is created, I can't access the created class:
[Class not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/namhI.png)
I really don't understand how to how to deal with this. Please help me.

To start with, I tried looking at what's in my classspath. It was totally empty:

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
$
$ >
```

I decided to add the jar files I need manually to it. Now I have a list of .jars inside it and it didn't help anyway:
[list of jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEicq.png)

Comment: `java -jar` is likely how you are running this application / how that shell script (jazzer is probably a shell script? is running it). `java -jar` __completely__ disregards both `CLASSPATH` as well as any `-cp` option. It uses the classpath as listed in the manifest of that jar file. Hence, 'my $CLASSPATH is blank' is irrelevant (in general, using CLASSPATH isn't a good approach; one system has one CLASSPATH variable but many different java apps you could run should make that obvious.

Comment: Note that the image of the error (kind of a bad idea; you should paste actual errors, as text, that's much easier to scan) says 'use `--cp` and you are using `-cp`. Maybe just.. use `--cp` exactly like the error message is telling you? It might be a bit brash to say 'RTFEM' (Read the Freaking Error Message), but.. did you try what it is telling you to do? If you did, you should edit the question with what happens when you do. If you didn't.. go do that first :)